# OSX & SED - Delete all lines after line 25 in a directory of documents

Tags: macos, sed

I have a directory that contains thousands of txt files. I need to trim the files so every line after line 25 in each file is deleted. I am using Mac OSX 10.14.6.

How can I do this?

---

## Attempts I have made

After researching  I think SED in Mac OSX terminal is the best way to do this.

[This page](https://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/sed-remove-lines-file-unix-examples.html?m=1) gives examples on how to target lines in SED. So I think the SED command I would need is:

```
sed '1,25!d'
```

This tells SED to delete everything apart from lines 1 to 25. When I try it on a single file, it works.

I now need to expand it so it works on a directory of files.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309514/sed-apply-changes-in-multiple-files) says I can do that using SEDs -n and -i flags (it also mentions an -s flag that doesn't work on OSX).

So I think the code should be like this:

```
sed -n -i '1,25!d' *.txt
```

But when I try it, I get this error:

```
sed: 1: "filename": command a expects \ followed by text
```

I have tried other variations, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `q` command instead of `d` for faster execution and pipe it with `find + xargs` like this:

```sh
cd some_dir
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 sed -i.bak '25q'
```

Answer (score 4):

MacOS uses BSD sed, not GNU sed: read `man sed`

The `-i` option *requires* an argument in BSD sed. If you don't want a backup copy of the file, the argument is an empty string:

```sh
$ seq 50 | tee file1 > file2

$ wc file1 file2
 50  50 141 file1
 50  50 141 file2
100 100 282 total

$ sed -i '' -n '1,25p' file1 file2

$ wc file1 file2
 25  25  66 file1
 25  25  66 file2
 50  50 132 total
```